# How to know when dragging a tab has finished?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that moves my pinned tabs to the active window: http://screencast.com/t/bRroTVda

It works great, with one exception:
When switching to another Chrome window by clicking on a tab in that window, I can't use `chrome.tabs.move` to move my pinned tabs to the newly activated window. `runtime.lastError` in the callback says

> Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab)

My problem now is: There seems to be no event that I can subscribe to that is raised when the user stops dragging.

What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retry moving tabs until the error goes away. To rate-limit the number of calls to 10 per second, use `setTimeout(yourFunctionThatCallsChromeTabsMove, 100);`.

Comment: The usage of `setTimeout` is deprecated, isn't it? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages: "If your extension uses window.setTimeout() or window.setInterval(), switch to using the alarms API instead.". The alarms API however seems to make only weak promises on when and if an alarm is raised: "For performance reasons, the alarm may have been delayed an arbitrary amount beyond this." and "when can be set to less than 1 minute after "now" without warning but won't actually cause the alarm to fire for at least 1 minute." And one minute is way too long

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The event page only shuts down if the extension has been idle for some time (10 seconds). `setTimeout` with short intervals (such as 100ms) is well under this treshold.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth First off, nobody forces anyone to use Event pages. So it's not in general deprecated. Second, Event pages don't unload immediately, they wait for a few seconds of idle time. So a `setTimeout` with that frequency would make the page stay loaded. What documentation means is that an Event page won't, in general, wait for the timeout to occur.

Comment: @Xan, Rob W: So you are saying a short interval is always reliable even on Event pages?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth No, `setTimeout` is not "always reliable" event with short intervals. The factor that makes setTimeout with the short interval reliable in this case is the fact that you're calling a Chrome extension API (`chrome.tabs.move`) that flags the extension as "not idle", thus preventing it from shutting down.