# How to find out if a user is dragging a tab

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to figure out, if a user is dragging a tab, any tab. I don't care which tab it is, I just need to know, if any tab is being dragged.

What is the best way to do this?

Please note: I asked [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460665/how-to-know-when-dragging-a-tab-has-finished). However, in that other question I wanted to know, when dragging stopped so I could perform my move operation. The solution given there (retrying until it works) doesn't seem to apply to this new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built a solution based on the fact that Chrome doesn't allow the moving of tabs in the window that contains a tab that is currently being dragged.
In this case, `chrome.runtime.lastError.message` will be `Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab)`.

I utilize this by getting the first tab of the focused window and moving it to its index. Because I use its own index, there isn't actually a visual change, when the operation succeeds.

```
var Chrome = {
    isUserDragging: function (callback) {
        chrome.windows.getAll({ populate: true }, function (windows) {
            var window = windows.filter(function (x) {
                return x.type === 'normal' && x.focused && x.tabs
                       && x.tabs.length;
            })[0];
            if (window === undefined)
                return;
            var tab = window.tabs[0];
            chrome.tabs.move(tab.id, { index: tab.index }, function () {
                callback(
                    chrome.runtime.lastError !== undefined &&
                    chrome.runtime.lastError.message.indexOf('dragging') !== -1);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
Chrome.isUserDragging(function(userIsDragging) {
    if(userIsDragging)
        // do something
    else
        // do something else
});
```

Now, based on this, I built a polling mechanism using `setTimeout` that checks periodically if the user is still dragging and executes an action, when the user stopped dragging.

The full implementation can be seen [here](https://github.com/dhilgarth/GlobalPinnedTabs/blob/1.0/chrome.js#L46) and it uses [these](https://github.com/dhilgarth/GlobalPinnedTabs/blob/1.0/periodicExecutor.js) [two](https://github.com/dhilgarth/GlobalPinnedTabs/blob/1.0/multiDelegate.js) helper classes.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to tell whether any tab is being "dragged" (=mouse button held down on a tab).

If you want to know that a tab drag has *occurred* (opposed to "is about to happen"), then you could use the [`chrome.tabs.onMoved`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onMoved) (moved within a tab) and/or [`chrome.tabs.onAttached`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onAttached) / [`chrome.tabs.onDetached`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onDetached) events.

Comment: That's a pity. I really need to know if a drag is currently in process. My extension is adding tabs to every new window. When the user drags a tab out of a window, a new window is create. My extension detects this and creates its tabs. However, this stops the dragging, making dragging a tab to another window impossible if it creates a new window along the way, even if that window is temporary: http://screencast.com/t/ZpkL3rE0ty Therefore, I need to queue the logic of my extension until dragging has stopped.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth You could use the onDetached event to detect that the new window is the result of detaching the tab, and wait until the user interacts with the page (e.g. via a focus/input event in a content script) before you insert the new tabs. Quite a work around, but seemingly better than destroying the tab drag feature.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will see if that works. I am also working on something based on your answer from yesterday. I am moving a tab in the focused window to its index, i.e. there won't be a visible move. However, if the user is dragging a tab, thi returns the same error as yesterday `Tabs cannot be edited right now (user may be dragging a tab)`. I will try to use both in combination. BTW: Is this error message always in English or is it in the browser's language?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth The message is always English. It's defined here: https://src.chromium.org/viewvc/chrome/trunk/src/chrome/browser/extensions/api/tabs/tabs_constants.cc?revision=281468#l88

Comment: I just posted my findings if you are interested.